# Group_split function & Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, split, sparklyr

I wonder if there is a function like `dplyr::group_split()` to use in Sparklyr context (method Databricks) with a Spark dataframe. ChatGPT says group_split works fine but i'm getting the error:

> Error in UseMethod("group_split") :
> no applicable method for 'group_split' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"

Here's an example:

```
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")   # my Spark connection


df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("a","a","b","b","c"),
                          c(1,2,3,3,5), 
                          c(3,3,4,2,2)))

df %>%
copy_to(sc,.)  %>% 
dplyr::group_by(V1) %>%
group_split()
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot!

Filipa

Comment: I'm sorry, i missed that part. Well, among others, i'm loading tidyverse, dplyr (although it's already included in tidyverse)  and sparklyr.